# Missing table in database

Tags: grails

hello I have domain class User and I created myself controller to register people.When I run the project and enter the fields and press enter I get this error  by:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: Hibernate operation: could not extract ResultSet; bad SQL grammar [n/a]; nested exception is
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column this_.id does not exist
```

I am connected to postgresql .I have all other domain classes have their own table in the database, but the domain class doesn't have which I think is the reason I get this error,how can I fix it?

```
    class User {
    String login
    String password
    String name


    static constraints = {
      login size: 3..20 , unique: true, nullable: false
        password size: 3..20, unique: false, nullable: false
        name size: 3..20, unique: false, nullable: false
    }

}

    class UserController {
    def scaffold = User
    def login = {}
    def authenticate = {
        def user = User.findByLoginAndPassword(params.login, params.password)
        if(user){
            session.user = user
            flash.message = "Hello ${user.name}!"
            redirect(controller:"entry", action:"list")
        }else{
            flash.message = "Sorry, ${params.login}. Please try again."
            redirect(action:"login")
        }
    }

    def logout = {
        flash.message = "Goodbye ${session.user.name}"
        session.user = null
        redirect(controller:"entry", action:"list")
    }
}

class RegisterUserController {
def index() { }
def register(String user,String password,String name) {
       def user2=new User(login: user,password : password,name: name)
        if (user2.validate() && user2.save() )  {
            redirect(url: "http://localhost:8080")
        } else {
        }
    }
}
```

I get error on the :  if (user2.validate() && user2.save() )

the application.yml file:

```
hibernate:
cache:
    queries: false
    use_second_level_cache: true
    use_query_cache: false
    region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
  dataSource:
pooled: true
jmxExport: true
driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
username: postgres
password:
    environments:
development:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: create-drop
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/new
        username: postgres
        password:
test:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: update
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/new
        username: postgres
        password:
production:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: update
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/new
        username: postgres
        password:
```

Comment: please provide your domain details. With this information it's not possible to tell exact reason why exception is coming.

Comment: And provide the Config.groovy (or application.yml) plz.

Comment: Probably I have to change something in the application.yml settings in order to recreate every new domain class table?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to call validate() because save() already calls it.

Try this

```
 if (user2.save(flush:true, failOnError: true) )  {
                redirect(url: "http://localhost:8080")
    }
```

With failOnError you can be more sure about error.

Also if this doesn't help try to change your Class name 
"User" to something else for ex. "MyUser"
I had faced with that issue in postgresql and changing class name resolved it if i don't remember wrong..